# Why is my Tailwind ract native not changing anything?

Tags: react-native, tailwind-css

I am working on a project, in project, i want to use tailwuind, I installed it like its shown in npms documentation,
I imported and use it as shown, it won't return error, but it just won't do anythink.

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you show the complete code? Maybe the problem is caused for another part of the code.

Comment: @MarceloFreire here,i added it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

I just follow the instructions on the documentation.

Install the library run the following command on your terminal.

```sh
npm install tailwind-rn
```

or

```sh
yarn add tailwind-rn
```

After this, I ran the command to set up the library.

```sh
npx setup-tailwind-rn
```

In your `tailwind.config.js` you must add on `content` the paths of files that use the tailwind. For me, I added all .js files from the folder `components`.

```js
module.exports = {
  content: ['./components/**/*.{js,jsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
  corePlugins: require('tailwind-rn/unsupported-core-plugins'),
}
```

> The code above isn't exists on documentation.

After this I run a command to build the tailwind with:

```sh
yarn build:tailwind
```

or watching the changes

```sh
yarn dev:tailwind
```

And finally, you can run your project for iOS or Android.

This works for me.

[image: expo-tailwind-example]

You can see the [source code project example on github](https://github.com/marcelofreires/expo-tailwind-example).

To see this running on your device just follow the repository instructions above.

Answer (score 2):

It happens because tailwind-rn generates only the CSS it is really needed and everytime you add a tailwind class to an element, you should let tailwindCSS generate a new style.css file (it does this automatically).

Your code looks OK, but you should run tailwind as well also as a react-script, just edit your package.json file and add this following line:

```
"dev:tailwind": "concurrently \"tailwindcss --input input.css --output tailwind.css --no-autoprefixer --watch\" \"tailwind-rn --watch\" ",
```

Then, if you use yarn just type:

```
yarn run dev:tailwind
```

or with npm

```
npm run dev:tailwind
```

Please make sure you have concurrently installed (npm i -g concurrently).

After running this, start your application as you usually do (on another terminal/cmd), and this should work now.

Comment: Did exect what u said, but still nothing....

Answer (score 1):

tailwind css configuration in react native expo-

```
step-1=> npm i tailwindcss-react-native
step-2=> npm i tailwindcss -D
step-3=> npx tailwindcss init

step-4=> in tailwind.config.js replace content with 

  content: ["./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "./screens/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
      "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
      "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"
    ],

step-5=> go to babel.config.js
and after presets put 
   plugins: ["tailwindcss-react-native/babel"],


step-6=> in App.js put
import { TailwindProvider } from 'tailwindcss-react-native';
and wrap all components with 
<TailwindProvider>
--------components-----
</TailwindProvider>
```

**NOTE: Do not include < TailwindProvider > in any component other than App.js otherwise it will not work.**

Answer (score 0):

in tailwind it's important for CSS to continuously changes and make changes in output.css file. For this you can just use at the same time while you run live server for your react file-

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch
```

or just follow the proper installation documentation of [TailwindCLI](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation)

Answer (score 0):

In root of app I needed to wrap it in . if anyone has problem with Tailwind, u can just go to https://github.com/marcelofreires/expo-tailwind-example and check each file how its set up, and find where they missed out...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).