# Tailwind-rn not doing anything

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo, tailwind-css

i cant seem to get **tailwind-rn** to work on my app, i have tried all the suggestions made everywhere but still can't figure out whats wrong. CSS files and json are building properly when i run `yarn build:tailwind`.

Here is my code, please feel free to ask for more info...

**App.js**

```js
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { useTailwind } from "tailwind-rn";
import { TailwindProvider } from "tailwind-rn";
import utilities from "./tailwind.json";

export default function App() {
  const tw = useTailwind();
  return (
    <TailwindProvider utilities={utilities}>
      <View style={tw("justify-center flex-1 items-center")}>
        <Text style={tw("text-red-600 justify-center")}>
          Open up App.js to start working on your!
        </Text>
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
      </View>
    </TailwindProvider>
  );
}
```

**Tailwind-config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  content: ["./*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
  corePlugins: require("tailwind-rn/unsupported-core-plugins"),
};
```

**My directory**

[image]

I have tried all the recommendations here:
[Why is my Tailwind ract native not changing anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71600495/why-is-my-tailwind-ract-native-not-changing-anything)

the official GitHub repo for tailwind-rn.

I am expecting my app's UI to update using tailwind but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Did you edit the `global.css`/`input.css` file to add these?

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```