# Tailwind CSS not working with React Native EXPO app that is configured correctly

Tags: react-native, expo, tailwind-css, nativewind

Tailwind css already cinfigured in a freshly created new react native expo app. But tailwind does not work even though project is configured according to the docs.

**package.json file**

```json
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "build:tailwind": "tailwindcss --input input.css --output tailwind.css --no-autoprefixer && tailwind-rn",
    "dev:tailwind": "concurrently \"tailwindcss --input input.css --output tailwind.css --no-autoprefixer --watch\" \"tailwind-rn --watch\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~48.0.18",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "tailwind-rn": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "concurrently": "^8.2.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.26",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I already tried this question answeres.But it didn't work. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71600495/why-is-my-tailwind-ract-native-not-changing-anything](https://stackoverflow.com)